# c# convert fixed document to xps, but xps viewer will not open the new created xps file

Tags: c#, xps, fixeddocument

i am trying to take a fixed document in c# and convert it to an xps and then save the xps so that i may attach it to an outlook email, but after i create the xps file and for testing purposes try to open the xps file in the xps file viewer, i get an error saying that the file cannot be opened, copy of the portion of the code where i am converting the fixed doc to an xps is pasted below:

```
//save fixed document in temp directory as xps document
            string filename = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\TempFixedDocument.xps";
            System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
            XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(filename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
            xw.WriteAsync(fxdDoc);
            xpsd.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you use `WriteAsync`, but not wait until writing is finished. You should wait until file writing is finished and only then close the document.

You can use await keyword:

```
await xw.WriteAsync(fxdDoc);
```

Comment: What is i just use write instead of the wrtieAsync

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM, I REPLACED THE WRITE ASYNC AND JUST USED THE WRITE. THANK YOU AGAIN, MUCH APPRECIATED.